# Неправильно вывод даты Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, дата, datetime, char

В базе данных строка
`INSERT INTO "S_ДЕТИ_СОТРУДНИКОВ" ("СЛУЖАЩИЙ_ИД","ФАМИЛИЯ","ИМЯ","ОТЧЕСТВО","ДЕНЬ_РОЖДЕНИЯ") VALUES ('100','Гумилев','Иван','Иванович',TO_DATE('16.10.02','DD.MM.RR'));`

при вводе команды выводит только все года в 01, хотя в бд от 0 до 10
`TO_CHAR ("ДЕНЬ_РОЖДЕНИЯ",'dd/mm/yy')`
Что делаю не так?
Документацию читал, стаж работы 1,5 года, не знаю, что не так.

Comment: Что значит `RR` в `DD.MM.RR`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html